# Raspbian started lagging, tried to reboot and now stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor

Tags: raspbian

Momentarily shows the Raspberry Pi splash screen then sits on a black screen with a blinking cursor.  I've checked the SD card on Window using Paragon software and SD card is almost full.  I dont know how to go about finding what is taking all the space and don't know if that will even help it boot.  Appreciate any help.